# Not able to run bin/hadoop on a hadoop cluster in pseudo-distributed mode

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I had successfully installed hadoop cluster on a VM having SUSE Linux in pseudo-distributed mode. It was working properly and was able to run all the `bin/hadoop` commands and execute map reduce jobs.

But strangely now it has starting giving me this weird error:

```
+================================================================+
|      Error: HADOOP_HOME is not set correctly                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please set your HADOOP_HOME variable to the absolute path of   |
| the directory that contains hadoop-core-VERSION.jar            |
+================================================================+
```

I am not able to understand why this is happening. I am able to do `jps` and it runs all the Daemons properly but not able to do `bin/hadoop`.

There is no problem of permissions here and path as it was working fine few hours before.

Comment: please check which folder your running the bin/hadoop command from ? If you want to run it from any where in your hardisk you have to set the installation folder in PATH variable..

Comment: I am running the bin/hadoop or bin/stop-all.sh etc commands from the same directory where bin is present. As I mentioned I was able to run all the map reduce jobs and everything properly but suddenly this problem started.

Comment: I have seen the the command complaining about HADOOP_HOME being not set but that didn't prevent me from executing the hadoop.. could you please paste in the complete output on executing the command?

Comment: This is the complete output which I am getting after executing command.

Comment: what does "echo $HADOOP_HOME" throws??

Comment: Already checked this. It does not output anything when I do that inside hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u5.

Comment: Try exporting HADOOP_HOME variable. Also add HADOOP_HOME o your .bashrc file in the home directory and append $HADOOP_HOME/bin to PATH variable